# Convert this SQL approach into Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

I have the following example used in MSSQL and was wanting to convert it to Oracle. The @@ROWCOUNT is not valid in Oracle and was wondering if there is an approach to do the same thing.

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PL/SQL equivalent is:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET ... WHERE Column1='SomeValue';
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT=0 THEN
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...);
END IF;
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle supports the `merge` syntax:

```
merge into Table1 using dual on (Column1 = 'SomeValue')
     when not matched then insert (...) values (...)
     when matched then update set ...;
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me like an UPDATE-or-INSERT (UPSERT) operation. The Standard SQL way to do this is using a MERGE statement. Both Oracle 10g and SQL Server 2008 support MERGE so if you stick to that method you'll have a solution that works on both platforms.